# Are pending flags no longer displayed?

Tags: support, flags

Recently I've flagged 2-3 posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034469/how-can-i-make-vertical-active-tabs-either-using-bootstrap-or-any-angular-compa) (this one as too broad), but those flags are not shown to me at the [flag summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3995261) (neither as helpful, declined, etc., nor as pending) and if I open the flagging dialog, just "spam", "rude or abusive" and "in need of moderator intervention" options are shown, but there isn't any "you have already flagged this" thing displayed.

Is this a bug? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

When you hit 3k reputation you unlocked the [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to [cast close and reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Looking at your [network reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/4965921/yakovl?tab=reputation) you crossed 3k reputation around February this year:

> [image]

You mentioned that you 'flagged' the question as "too broad", but when you are able to cast close/open votes, you don't flag questions for closure, you cast close votes on them, e.g.:

> [image: cast too broad close vote]

as opposed to (screenshot from my account on [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com) where I have <3k reptutation, hence the different colours):

> [image: flag as too broad]

You can view your close/reopen votes by clicking on the link in your profile (it's greyed out for me because votes are private):

> [image]